# Where can I find weather data on ambient outside illumination?

Tags: light, database

I am looking to analyze outside lighting data and its implications on human health regionally, but I can't seem to find a ubiquitous database that contains outside lux illumination data throughout the continental US. This is essential to my study and seems to be measurable, but virtually nonexistent on each climactic database I request from.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: you will not find it in lux here but you might be able to convert it from this site : https://www.timeanddate.com/

Comment: simply input your location in sunrise and sunset and you will get the graph telling the light level during the day/night.

Comment: I am looking for the source of this data. not how to convert specific energy quantities. Do either of you have access to this data or have any leads on where it might be?

Comment: @ZacheryUtt Are you looking for natural (sun) or artificial light (street lamps)? Probably the latter?

Comment: As I understand it, you're asking for a dataset that shows how bright it is outside during daylight hours for varying locations.... and not just based upon ideal amounts of sunlight but weather conditions?

Comment: If so... I'm not sure you're going to find such a dataset with much validity.  Standard weather stations in the US report [these variables](https://www.weather.gov/asos/asostech), but while there is a definite decrease from idealized light values with increasing cloud depth, fog, haze, and precipitation, there's not nearly enough relationship to allow you to actually calculate the lighting intensity from that data.

Comment: I believe you can find datasets of the % of daylight hours with cloudcover using that station data (or else could calculate it)... and that probably offers useful potential for connecting to health. But in terms of actual light values, I don't believe there's any useful set of actual data. There may be estimations others have already attempted to derive out from the cloudcover+other meteorological variables, and there may be papers looking into how valid these are; they could be dug into if that is your interest direction... but they won't be actual data, just estimates, having probable flaws.

Comment: Some places, at least the Oklahoma mesonet, probably a few other research locations around the country, have a radiometer, which calculates how much solar energy reaches the station.  That may offer a little better estimate than just cloudcover... though I'm still not sure it will fully account for variations in light diffusion/scattering and such.  But it might be closer to reality, or at least improve upon the initial poor estimates from the more basic meteorologic data a bit.

Comment: And I figure there's almost certainly data on lux taken at specific sites during research projects... many of which may really be unrelated to meteorology/similar subjects (thinking like photography, self-driving car calibration, sports events, who knows what). But I don't know if anything capable of representing regional variation decently would be available... and sort of doubt it... but since it'd be outside of the known horizon of most physical scientists, I'm not sure any of us will be able to definitively conclude it doesn't exist, only be able to state "we don't know of it".

Answer (score 3):

One direction to look in might be the various GIS systems that exist to forecast the amount of light that will reach photovoltaic (solar panel) installations. I don't know about the US, but I would be very surprised if there isn't one - try googling for "PV GIS" or similar.

Now, that will give you insolation (illuminance) in W/m<sup>2</sup>. It may be further broken down into direct and indirect insolation (that's direct sunlight and diffuse light from the sky or clouds), or it may be a single global figure.

Since you're after the information in lux rather than W/m<sup>2</sup>, you'll need to convert it. This will necessarily be an approximate process, but so long as you don't need very high accuracy it should be quite doable. Lux is at base a measurement of power density, just like W/m<sup>2</sup>, but it's modified by a [frequency-dependent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function) that represents the sensitivity of human vision. So you'll need to assume a spectrum for the sunlight, and then apply the conversion curve (which is an international standard, and hopefully available on the internet).

Comment: From what I've seen, the quick work around is to assume monochromatic light with a wavelength of 555 nm, which is a green coloured wavelength the human eye is most sensitive to. At that wavelength [1 lumen = 1/683 W](https://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=191124).

Comment: @Fred because that's the wavelength that the eye is the most sensitive to, assuming that all of the power is at that wavelength will give a substantial overestimate.